# when condition ansible - list the kibana plugin if the kibana status is green

Tags: ansible

I have 2 ansible tasks regarding the listing of the current kibana plugins if there are installed or not and I want to put a condition, "**list the kibana plugin if the kibana status is green**"

**1. If the kibana server is up and running I have the below json result: :**

```
{
  "accept_ranges": "bytes",
  "attempts": 1,
  "cache_control": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
  "changed": false,
  "connection": "close",
  "content_length": "9986",
  "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "cookies": {},
  "cookies_string": "",
  "date": "Thu, 30 Mar 2023 08:44:37 GMT",
  "elapsed": 0,
  "json": {
    "status": {
      "overall": {
        "icon": "success",
        "nickname": "Looking good",
        "since": "2023-03-30T08:44:37.504Z",
        "state": "green",
        "title": "Green",
        "uiColor": "secondary"
      },
```

**2. Sometimes, the kibana server is not up and running and I get below output:**

```
TASK [task.kibana : Check Kibana status] *************************************
Thursday 30 March 2023  16:22:19 +0000 (0:00:00.024)       0:00:17.525 ******** 
FAILED - RETRYING: Check Kibana status (1 retries left).
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 1, "changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5601/api/status"}
```

**3. I want to create a task that is listing the current kibana plugin installed if the Kibana Server has the status green (server is up and running) based on the registered variable "kibanaApi "**

```
- name: Check Kibana status
  uri:
    url: "http://192.168.1.1:5601/api/status"
    method: "GET"
  register: kibanaApi
  delay: 10
  check_mode: no
  changed_when: false
  tags: ['healthcheck']


- name: List current kibana plugins 
  command: "{{ kibanaPluginCommand }} list --allow-root"
  when: "{{ kibanaApi.json |json_query('json.status.overall[?state == `green`]') }}"
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: true
  tags:
    - kibana-plugins
```

**4. The output error of the task "List current kibana plugin" is giving me errors:**

```
    TASK [task.kibana : List current kibana plugins] **********************
    Thursday 30 March 2023  16:22:49 +0000 (0:00:00.038)       0:00:47.912 ******** 
    [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
    delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ kibanaApi.json
    |json_query('json.status.overall[?state == `green`]') }}
    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{ kibanaApi.json |json_query('json.status.overall[?state == `green`]') }}' failed. The error was: Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\n'dict object' has no attribute 'json'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/builds/task.kibana/tasks/main.yml':
```

Comment: (a) it very clearly says "don't wrap when in mustaches" (b) I presume you're looking for the `|default` filter, as in `kibanaApi.json | default({"json":""}, true)` although I also suspect you have double `json`-ed your setup, but without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no one can possibly know what the shape is supposed to look like

Answer (score 0):

the solution for my question is :

```
- name: List current kibana plugins
  command: "{{ kibanaPluginCommand }} list --allow-root"
  when: kibanaApi is search('Green')
  register: kibanaCurrentPlugins
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  tags:
    - kibana-plugins
```

**or**

```
- name: List current kibana plugins
  command: "{{ kibanaPluginCommand }} list --allow-root"
  register: kibanaCurrentPlugins
  failed_when: false
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  tags:
    - kibana-plugins
```